# Why does this post get downvoted and close voted for "opinion biased question" and not this one?

Tags: discussion

I posted [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797250/what-is-the-most-concise-solution-for-text-and-file-processing) which I tried to make the least "opinion biased" by adding precise adjectives such as "most concise (=short)" or "powerful" and not simply "best". I took the time to write a working example so answerers could try to write the same algorithm in other languages in order to compare the length. Still after all these efforts I get downvoted and close voted for "opinion biased question".

I learned [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) hoping that it would be a convenient language for data and file processing and I found out it is not really since you [can't directly overwrite files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python). In order not to reproduce the same mistake I am asking more experienced programmers what would be -in their argumented opinion- the best (that is, all the adjectives I used in my thread) solution to learn. Indeed, I think it is fair to say that it would be a waste of time to learn all the existing languages just to check which one is best fitted to data and file processing.

So is it forbidden to ask so? If not, is my way of asking chokingly bad, rude or inappropriate? If it is indeed forbidden, why don't questions [such as these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309662/comparing-the-uses-applications-of-java-vs-python) seem to know the same fate as mine?

Comment: Did you not see when that question was asked?  Several years ago.  Times were different back then.

Comment: That last question you linked is 5 years old. The rules have changed over time. Now that you've brought attention to it here, it too will probably share the same fate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that question out. It's been taken care of.

Comment: The problem with your question is also included in your text in this one - **in their argumented opinion**. You're asking for opinions for "best" (rephrasing as "most concise" or "powerful" doesn't change that), and those types of questions are indeed not appropriate here. We don't offer advice or recommendations, and that includes "what's the best language to do this" or "what's the best algorithm" or "what's the most concise language" or any variations on that theme.

Comment: Oh really you don't ? That sounds a little silly since as I pointed it out most the old threads asking for opinion are generally strongly upvoted. I thought the point of SO was to help the community ?

Comment: That post you linked to...[aaaand it's gone](http://images.wikia.com/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/f/f0/And_its_gone_original.jpg)

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude, I just enjoy that thing from South Park.  Look it's not a "garbage community", there are rules and they are in place for a reason.  There's tons of people who ask crappy questions, and it's not that your question was a "crappy" one but it didn't follow the rules.  Unfortunately that's how rules work.  It's not worth getting angry about - it's good that you asked a question here.  And I believe downvotes on Meta are different from those on SO.

Comment: I'm not rude to you personnaly either but I'm a bit shocked by how I am treated on this forum lately, I'm trying to understand my mistakes but get downvoted even when I honestly ask on meta... so w/e. I'll still stay here because I get good answers from time to time but I won't care about my reputation anymore.

Comment: Calm down @Wicelo.  You need to understand that SO isn't here to solve all the world's problems.  SO has a mission and the community makes practical decisions to ensure that this site can fulfill that mission.  This site is full of people that contribute their time without payment (probably), so we need to respect their efforts.

Comment: Do you have any other examples that we might have missed?

Comment: So of course the mods rush in and close that question of 5 years ago that was in the community wiki. I think questions should be moved not closed. Isn't programmers available for moving questions off-topic at stackoverflow?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Answer (score -13, accepted):

I found a part of the answer to my question: [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077)

People downvoting this thread on meta (which is exactly the place for these questions) just proves the point.

Anyway, since we can't ask for advice on Stack Overflow, I'll ask on [Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit). We shall see how I am received there.

Comment: You will see a lot more downvotes on Meta because it is more opinion based in its purpose.  Even mods get downvoted.  Don't take it personally.  The votes are about ideas and content, not people (or atleast they shouldn't be).

Comment: BTW: At the moment your question and answer have one upvote each (and a total of 5 downvotes together)... That's really not that overwhelming.

Comment: So, which camp of user do you fall into?

Comment: You don't lose rep here, so I don't see why getting downvoted for disagreement is such a big deal to you.

Comment: downvoting in meta doesn't lose you rep, it just means they don't agree with your opinion. meta is for opinions on how stack overflow should run

Answer (score 9):

Actually the close reason that got the majority vote is:

> "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

And this was due to this line in your question:

> Is it shell scripting with sed and awk, or maybe Perl or other ?

You've turned your question into an invitation for people to submit their favorite technology. That's a big "no-no" on Stack Overflow.

But you are asking why your question is *also* opinion-based. The problem is here:

> So what is, from your experienced point of view, the solution that -in general- requires the least number of line of code and that is the **most intuitive** but that is also **powerful** and gives the ability to do a wide variety of tasks.

I've highlighted the two most problematic expressions in your request. What proves to be "intuitive" is a matter of opinion, and "powerful" is vague. If you have a notion of how one can precisely rank algorithms according to their degree of being "intuitive" or "powerful", then you ought to detail that in your question.

The fact that some other question has flown under the radar does not make your question okay. There are multiple reasons that some questions that should be closed remain open. Sometimes, it's because they were posted when the rules were different. Sometimes, it's because they were posted on a topic that few people read. Sometimes, it's just luck.

Comment: Why is it a no-no ? The whole point is not to simply send a favorite technology but also to send the arguments that support the choice to help me in my choice.

Comment: The close reason tells you why: "they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". The idea is not that SO is claiming that you can't **ever** ask people for what technology you should use, but that you cannot ask this **on SO**. You want to ask on a discussion forum somewhere, fine. You want to ask your friends at the coffee shop, fine. Don't ask on SO. That's how it is. If you want to change this rule, then prepare an argument as to *why* the rule should be changed and post it on Meta.

Comment: @Wicelo There's a very long story to it. In short, it invites spam and low quality answers. Seeing as they were dragging down SO, they even tried to make a site for them, (Programmers.SE) but that degraded as well and so SE redefined P.SE did away with opinionated questions altogether.

Comment: @Wicelo Ah, I found the link explaining how they *tried* support subjective questions. It just didn't work out. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/169611

Comment: @Wicelo While NotProgrammingRelated.SE (which later because Programmers.SE) *was* originally created for those questions, [reposting the same question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/256057/40980) is frowned upon... P.SE even has the same "no recommendations" close reason that SO has.  Furthermore, [cross posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/213963).